# WebView.loadUrl not working, showing blank page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a basic Web View application, with demo.html and demo.js files. App opened without errors but showing a blank page!

demo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>    
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="demo.js" type="text/javascript" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="form1" onSubmit="return showInfo()" autocomplete="on">
      First name:<input type="text" id="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

demo.js:

```
function showInfo()
{
    var str1= document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var str2= document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var res = str1.concat(' '+str2);
    alert('Hi,' +res);
}
```

Here I loaded URL:

```
 WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView1);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Web/demo.html");
```

When I tried to open the same demo.html on my PC , its not opened. Then I removed `<script src="demo.js" type="text/javascript" />` then It opened the page. Is this means Java script is not supported ?

I checked my PC JavaScript status with https://www.whatismybrowser.com/is-javascript-enabled
It says JavaScript is enabed in my browser, Wonder why its not working in my PC and android emulator !?

Thanks

Comment: whats in the javascript file

Comment: @RachelGallen updated question with js file

Comment: your file path must be incorrect. it works fine if you just put the script in script tags in the html document

Comment: demo.html and demo.js in same directory. demo.html is not opening in my PC too. without calling js in html file it is opening. may be issue with javascript in my browser !

Comment: works fine for me - what browser are you using? Did  you try just putting it in script tags in the head like i suggested

Comment: Yes, If I put js in html head then it works.

Comment: well then pls accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a tag at the end of your script call.

Your html should look like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="demo.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" onSubmit="return showInfo()" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" id="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Then it will work